# PHP crawler with cookie params as logged in

Tags: php, cookies, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to crawl info from website using logged in cookies as user. But instead of returning main logged page it returns me login page. Where can the problem be? The cookies are the same as logged in and more..

```
    class Crawl extends simple_html_dom
{

    protected $__headers;
    protected $__settings;
    protected $__tmp_data;

    private function __generate_headers_array()
    {
        $headers_array = array(
            TORRENT_COOKIE_UID,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_PASS,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_SESSID,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_GA,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_GAT,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_GADS,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_UNAM,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_UTMA,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_UTMC,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_CFD,
            TORRENT_COOKIE_CFD2
        );
        $return_array = array();

        foreach ( $headers_array as $value ) {
            $value = explode('|', $value);
            $return_array[] = array(
                'key'   => $value[0],
                'value' => $value[1]
            );
        }

        return $return_array;
    }

    private function __prepare($headers)
    {
        $this->__set_headers($headers);
    }

    private function __set_context($data, $ref = FALSE)
    {
        $this->__prepare($data['headers']);

        $header = "User-Agent: User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5\r\n";
        $header .= "Cookie: " . trim($this->__headers) . "\r\n";
        if ( $ref ) {
            $header .= "Referer: " . $ref . "\r\n";
        }

        $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => "GET",
                'header' => trim($header)
            )
        );

        /*echo '<pre>';
        print_r($opts);
        echo '</pre>';*/


        return stream_context_create($opts);
    }

    private function __set_headers($headers_data)
    {
        foreach ( $headers_data as $key => $value ) {
            $this->__headers .= $value['key'] . '=' . $value['value'] . '; ';
        }
    }

    public function test_parse($url)
    {
        $this->__settings['parse_url'] = $url;
        $this->__tmp_data['context'] = $this->__set_context(array('headers' => $this->__generate_headers_array()));
        $this->__tmp_data['dom'] = file_get_contents($this->__settings['parse_url'], false, $this->__tmp_data['context']);
        $data = array();

        //$data['user_check'] = $this->__tmp_data['dom']->find('a[href="myaccount"] b', 0)->plaintext;
        return $this->__tmp_data['dom'];
    }

}
```

constants:

```
    define('TORRENT_COOKIE_SESSID', 'PHPSESSID|pqlo6pivr51unu25q4612s9vi1'); //
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_UID', 'uid|1024327'); //
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_PASS', 'pass|a456429bd4ff18dc9da36319bc6e49b8');
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_GADS', '__gads|ID=601c94825383b103:T=1416866412:S=ALNI_MbTOQSkOo7kG9E7HlDo8BqTqh7EjA'); //
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_GA', '_ga|GA1.2.551848255.1397222362'); //
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_GAT', '_gat|1'); //
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_UNAM', '__unam|2632f74-14550f19986-275981c3-598');
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_UTMA', '__utma|232870683.551848255.1397222362.1418861839.1419093481.203');
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_UTMC', '__utmc|232870683');
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_CFD', '__cfduid|d8d3e95541aa1ba0bee41c226df3f79c81421092422');
define('TORRENT_COOKIE_CFD2', '__cfduid|d64e908e790b3e473f9321064ea2b70a61397222380387');
```

and the website I want to crawl http://www.torrent.ai/lt/torrents

Comment: You probably want to use curl or a scraping library for this.

Comment: nope, the problem is somewhere else. with this script I can log in and scrap everything else website, but not this one.